# Sockets(not working) SFML Cheeckers C++

Tags: c++, sockets, sfml

I am writting here to ask you for help. I have big problem with sockets SFML, with I cannot handle. I am codding cheekers, all works exept socket - LAN.

I am using string to buffer, not packages because I send only four numbers.: example: "1234" [Beginning_X,Beginning_Y,Target_X,Target_Y], I convert it to string and send by sockets then I spilt it on four int again. My code is little big, I am sorry I am begginer, but I believe that there is not to many to do to improve my code. Please help.

During launching it's needed to run .exe programm twice, ones put 's' - server, second 'c' - client
code: http://pastebin.com/EiWERt9q
main 939,  start sockets 1005, 1117 sending sockets, 1191 receiving sockets
I am polish so most code is written in my native language. 
Thanks again

Comment: This has nothing to do with sockets and everything to do with your not understanding `std::string` and C-style strings. You should review those chapters in your fine book.

Comment: `string tmp; sprintf((char*)tmp.c_str(), "%d", klikniety_X);` is a recipe for *undefined behavior*. and 1300+ lines of linked code? Yeah, no thanks.

Comment: I have no clue what your code is supposed to do, because it contains no comments and is written in a foreign language. Have a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/). That said, please learn to use `std::string`. `sprintf` is plain C. Don't mix them.

Comment: If you have problems, the first step is to write a [mcve]. In your case, take 4 integers, format them and send them. Cut out all the other code.